# Why does java app move with desktop spaces selection?

Tags: macos

If I switch desktop space my Java app window follows to the selected space. It doesn't matter which space I select, my java app always turns up on it. Is there some osX setting or java compile flag that pins the java app windows to the desktop space it was originally executing from?

Comment: In the dock, have you elected a space behavior for that app? (Does that app even show in the dock) - there are quite a few versions of macOS and Java as well as ways to build a java app. If no one has an answer you like in a couple days - consider using the edit to narrow down some versions of the OS and framework at least.

Comment: Doh! stupid me. That was it. I didnt set the app behaviour in the dock. Thank you for your prompt solution. BTW: Mojave, Java 8.

Comment: Go ahead and answer your question. @me again and I’ll vote for it, too having a proper answer will help others remember the fix :)